# Additional space between \gantttitle items

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

Here is an MWE of what I've written so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,
vgrid,
bar/.style={fill=blue}]{1}{21}
\gantttitle{Timeline}{21}\ganttnewline
\gantttitle{2019}{9}
\gantttitle{2020}{12}\\                     % title 3
\gantttitle{Q2}{3}
\gantttitle{Q3}{3}
\gantttitle{Q4}{3}
\gantttitle{Q1}{3}
\gantttitle{Q2}{3}
\gantttitle{Q3}{3} 
\gantttitle{Q4}{3}\\
\ganttgroup{First Visit}{1}{10}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

And the result is that in the title, the first row is one cell (Timeline), an empty row, 3rd row is two cells (2019, 2020), another empty row, and the last row is 8 cells (Q1,Q2, ...).
How should I change my code to remove the empty rows from the title?

Comment: Please make a complete MWE from your code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [Reduce space between title and bars in pgfgantt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162601/reduce-space-between-title-and-bars-in-pgfgantt?rq=1), you can use `title height=1`, and then modify `y unit title` to set the height of the title bars.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,
vgrid,
bar/.style={fill=blue},
y unit title=0.6cm,
title height=1
]{1}{21}
\gantttitle{Timeline}{21}\ganttnewline
\gantttitle{2019}{9}
\gantttitle{2020}{12}\\                     % title 3
\gantttitle{Q2}{3}
\gantttitle{Q3}{3}
\gantttitle{Q4}{3}
\gantttitle{Q1}{3}
\gantttitle{Q2}{3}
\gantttitle{Q3}{3} 
\gantttitle{Q4}{3}\\
\ganttgroup{First Visit}{1}{10}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```