# Remove empty rows in ganttchart title (gantttitlecalendar)

Tags: pgfgantt

When using `\ganttitlecalendar` from the [pgfgantt package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf), it automatically inserts empty rows between the title rows. Is there a smooth way to prohibit this without having to create my own title?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
x unit=0.7cm,
hgrid,
vgrid,
time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
bar/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!20},
compress calendar
]{2016-06}{2018-09}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
  \ganttbar{Task1}{2016-06}{2018-07} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this answer can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162693/1952

Comment: Perfect! Everything is in there. Thanks!